# Sum of Formula field

Tags: crystal-reports, formula, percentage

I have two values: `Value` and `Percentage`. To calculate the total, I just need to create a formula like this one:

```
({table.value} / 100.00) * {table.percentage}
```

My report shows the amount of sales grouping by product:

**Value----------Percent-----------Total**
Sum of Value---???---Sum of the formula above

The problem starts when I need to show the percent value grouped by products, I can't simply show a Sum of `Percent` and showing the Medium displays wrong value.

[image]

*Correct total based on the percentual.

For example, the second line of the table shows values grouped by product, as you can see, simply calculating the Medium shows `6,34` when it should be showing `8,32`.

So, I was thinking about creating another formula, just to calculate the `Percent` value when grouped, like this:

```
Sum ({@Calculated}, {product.product_id}) / Sum ({table.value}, {product.product_id}) * 100
```

When previewing, it shows the correct values, but when running, it throws an exception telling me that I can't Sum the `{@Calculated}` because it needs to be bound to a grouping.

Is there any way to recalculate the percentual value based on a formula?

Comment: were you able to find a solution on this>?

Comment: No, I ended up removing the % value...

Comment: can you show the formula for @Calculated?

Comment: Its a bit confusing....`in preview report is fine but when running throws exception`... Can you explain this?

Comment: @CoSpringsGuy it's the first code part of this question.

Comment: @Siva When using the `Sum` of the `@Calculated` formula while grouped by `{product.product_id}` only throws an exception when running, not when previewing (using the same database).

Comment: @Siva If I remove the `Sum ({@Calculated}, {product.product_id})` no exception is thrown. Anyway, I ended up removing this information from the report for now.

Comment: Ok is the issue resolved now